# General Topology- If $f:X \to Y$ is a map between spaces and if $X$ is separable, then the subspace $f(X) \subseteq Y$ is separable

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification

I'm having a hard time constructing the proof for this question. Here's what I have

Let $X$ be separable. Then $f(X) \subseteq Y$ is a subspace of $Y$. Without loss of generality, let $f$ be an open map. Since $X \subseteq X$ is open, $f(X) \subseteq Y$ is also open. By proposition there exists a countable dense subset $A \subseteq X$.

From here I just stated to choose $A=X$ and incorrectly closed the proof. Where should I go from here? Should I utilize the definition of the $f(X)$ subspace somehow?

There is a part 2 to this question involving 2nd countability with basically the same premise, so I'd like to understand the separability proposition first.

Thanks :)

Comment: You **cannot** assume that $f$ is an open map: doing so is an **enormous** loss of generality, as continuous maps are not in general open. There is only one reasonable approach: let $D$ be a countable dense subset of $X$, and try to show that $f[D]$ is a countable dense subset of $f[X]$.

Comment: I had a feeling that I couldn't just clump both open and closed cases in one, thanks. Going down the approach you suggest, how is proving that $f(D)$ is a separable subset of $f(X)$ easier/different? I'm not sure how to approach that conclusion.

Comment: In general continuous maps are neither open nor closed, so it’s not a matter of lumping together two cases. \\ The approach that I suggested is the one that ought to occur to you immediately: there really isn’t any other natural thing to do. And proving that $f[D]$ is a countable dense subset of $f[X]$ is very easy: countability is trivial, and denseness follows easily from the continuity of $f$.

Comment: The proposition is obviously false without extra assumption about $f$. Is $f$ continuous?

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Although it was not explicitly stated in the question I am looking at, I believe $f$ is a continuous map since I am being asked to prove that this statement is true.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Okay, I see now. Topology is a difficult area for me to construct proofs, so your advice has helped a lot. Thank you :)

Comment: Without continuity, counter-example can be constructed easily. See my counter-example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $D$ be countable dense in $X$. Then $f[D]$ is dense in $f[X]$: let $O$ be non-empty open in $f[X]$ so we can write $O= f[X] \cap O'$ where $O$ is open in $Y$.

So $f^{-1}[O']$ is open in $X$ as $f$ is continuous and it's non-empty too: pick $y \in O$ so $y \in f[X]$ so for some $x \in X$ we have $f(x)=y \in O \subseteq O'$ showing $x \in f^{-1}[O]$. So as $D$ is dense in $X$, we have some $d \in f^{-1}[O'] \cap D$ and so $f(d) \in f[D] \cap O$ and so $f[D]$ intersects $O$. Done.

You surely **cannot** assume $f$ is open. "WLOG", it's a huge loss of generality...

Comment: Without extra assumption about $f$, the proposition is false. The OP has never mentioned that $f$ is a continuous map. Without such assumption, the proposition is false. For example, let $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ as sets. However, equip $X$ with the trivial topology while $Y$ with the discrete topology. Set $f(x)=x$....

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan map = continuous function in many texts. And continuity is precisely enough anyway.